# How do I create header from other header values in Traefik

Tags: traefik

In Traefik, I want to take the values of headers that come from a forwarded auth, and add them to the ongoing request as a combined custom header.

I see that I can simply forward the headers using:

`authResponseHeaders = ["X-Auth-Token", "X-Token-Type"]`

What I really need to achieve is to combine these into another header (pseudo code):

`Authorization = X-Token-Type + " " + X-Auth-Token`

Our ongoing request needs to authenticate using the `Authorixation` header, but this would be incorrect unless (I think, I can't test this right now) I pass `Authorization` back from my forwarded auth, and use:

`authResponseHeaders = ["Authorization"]`

Caveat, I haven't tested the above as Traefik got deleted until I can prove it will work. Sad I know.

Is any of this rambling question possible?